# Why do I need to eject an ipod before disconnecting it?

Tags: ipod, eject, removable-media

Is there any good reason that I need to wait for iTunes to give me permission to remove an iPod from my computer?

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  It's possible not all the writes to the device have completed.  It's possible you may leave the filesystem in an inconsistent state, corrupting it.

Comment: Yup. Same principle applies to flash drives or any removable devices - don't remove the drive until all writes have finished.